# Issues With Redirection Using Button Created In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button using Javascript and I am trying to open a window with window.open(url). The "url" opens up correctly initially. But then I created another button and did the same as I did earlier but this time around the url redirection got messed up. Both the buttons now open up on the last url that I used. I want both the buttons to work exclusively and open the respective urls that have been mentioned in the code.

```
  <div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
  <div>
 <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7zqUR_RPEH8/VLxzHDIQXoI/AAAAAAAAAkM/388tnESCv9g/600/peacock-aeromech.jpeg" height="200px" 
  width="200px"/>
 </div>
  <div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/peacock-aeromech/p/itmdzdt4jdseczzh?pid=BLCDCYYHCKHVJDJG&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A112f129912.&affid=saurabhsu1","_self")
  }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
  <div>
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7OoAscM_6WI/VLxzGLzimNI/AAAAAAAAAj0/L424sw9xDIg/s1600/lego-school-bus.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px"/>
  </div>

   <div>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction1() {
   var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/lego-school-bus/p/itmdxsxgj7gfdzgk?pid=BLCDXSXFP3UTMYEX&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A11eaee7b19.&affid=saurabhsu1","_self")
   }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct. Both your buttons are calling myFunction(). Shouldnt that be myFunction1() for second button.

Comment: from where you are calling function1

Comment: Why do you create a button in your code. It doesn't do anything and not visible to the user as well.

Comment: @Vishwanath even if u make it myFunction1() the thing doesn't work.

Comment: @eyurdakul It is very much visible to the user and I have a constraint of using only HTML and Javascript for making a button and giving it a functionality.

Comment: Some of the links you got does not seem to work. I don't think its a redirection problem, its rather the links that does not work. And you can remove the line var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); since its not being used

Comment: i mean this;
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried executing the code you have provided and by changing the function call from the second button to call myFunction1 rather than myFunction, I was able to access the two urls separately.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
    <div>
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7zqUR_RPEH8/VLxzHDIQXoI/AAAAAAAAAkM/388tnESCv9g/600/peacock-aeromech.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
          var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
          window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/peacock-aeromech/p/itmdzdt4jdseczzh?pid=BLCDCYYHCKHVJDJG&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A112f129912.&affid=saurabhsu1", "_self")
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
    <div>
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7OoAscM_6WI/VLxzGLzimNI/AAAAAAAAAj0/L424sw9xDIg/s1600/lego-school-bus.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <button onclick="myFunction1()">Try it</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction1() {
          var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
          window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/lego-school-bus/p/itmdxsxgj7gfdzgk?pid=BLCDXSXFP3UTMYEX&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A11eaee7b19.&affid=saurabhsu1", "_self")
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I attached the code here for your reference. However, it is same as yours, apart from the invocation of the javascript function

Answer (score 2):

You have used same js function in both the buttons. to avoid confusions keep js at one place

```html
<div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
 <div>
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7zqUR_RPEH8/VLxzHDIQXoI/AAAAAAAAAkM/388tnESCv9g/s1600/peacock-aeromech.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px"/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
 <div>
  <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-7OoAscM_6WI/VLxzGLzimNI/AAAAAAAAAj0/L424sw9xDIg/s1600/lego-school-bus.jpeg" height="200px" width="200px"/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <button onclick="myFunction1()">Try it</button>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/peacock-aeromech/p/itmdzdt4jdseczzh?pid=BLCDCYYHCKHVJDJG&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A112f129912.&affid=saurabhsu1","_self")
   }
   function myFunction1() {
    window.open("http://dl.amazon.com/dl/lego-school-bus/p/itmdxsxgj7gfdzgk?pid=BLCDXSXFP3UTMYEX&srno=t_1&query=Lego&offer=b%3Amp%3Ac%3A11eaee7b19.&affid=saurabhsu1","_self")
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe add some explanation about the changes you made. Or a description about where the question asker went wrong.

Comment: @Tom I have written ample to make someone understand.

Comment: @Somendra Beautiful ! Seperating javascript from the code is the best way to do it.

Comment: @androidrill Hi, I was commenting on the answer posted by Somendra, not on your original question.

Comment: @Tom No issues brother.Thanks for contributing.